# VBA Search for Header, Copy, and Paste all data below header

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that searches for a column header name, finds the column, copies all the data below it, and then pastes it into cell A3 of another worksheet.

For example, on Sheet 1

```
+-----+------+-------+
| Row | Part | Price |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 | X    |     5 |
|   2 | y    |     6 |
|   3 | Z    |     7 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

So, the macro would search for "Part", Copy x, y, and z (the number of rows can change, So i cant just say copy B2:B4), and paste it into A3 of Sheet 2. 
Then, it would search for price, copy 5, 6, and 7, and paste it into B3 of Sheet 2. etc etc

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Cleanup() 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    PN = WorksheetFunction.Match("PART_NO", Rows("1:1"), 0) 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(PN).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") 
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you done until now? Try looking for the .Find Function and copying from the .Adress of this Range or the .Column as References

Comment: Start by looking at `Find()` - post back when you have some code.

Comment: Or if you know how the excel function MATCH works, look for that in VBA, also google how to get the last row if you know the column number.

Comment: Here is what I have so far:

Sub Cleanup()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
    PN = WorksheetFunction.Match("PART_NO", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    Sheets("Sheet1).Columns(PN).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
    
End Sub

This fails when it tries to paste into A3 (copy and paste area not the same size). I understand why it fails, but I can't figure out how to copy ONLY the rows in the column that have data, as opposed to the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Sub Cleanup()

    Dim arrCols, shtSrc As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, hdr, pn

    arrCols = Array("PART_NO", "QTY", "UNITS") '<< column headers to be copied

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Sheet1")              '<< sheet to copy from
    Set rngDest = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") '<< starting point for pasting

    'loop over columns
    For Each hdr In arrCols

        pn = Application.Match(hdr, shtSrc.Rows(1), 0)

        If Not IsError(pn) Then
            '##Edit here##
            shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Cells(2, pn), _
                         shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, pn).End(xlUp)).Copy rngDest
            '/edit
        Else
            rngDest.Value = hdr
            rngDest.Interior.Color = vbRed '<< flag missing column
        End If

        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 1)
    Next hdr

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, this is nearly exactly what I am looking for! However, is it possible to copy ONLY the data below the "header" column? The headers in my "copy from" sheet are not quite how i want the headers written on the "paste to sheet" so I only need the info below the header. Sorry, quite new to this stuff. 

Thanks!